# How to define a typescript import path relative to some root (using webpack)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, import

I'm writing a Vue application that has many components which are nested in different folders.  My folder structure looks something like this:

```
src folder
+components folder 
++partA folder
+++A.vue
+++AA.ts
+++subA folder
++++AAA.ts
++partB
+++B.vue
+++BB.ts
```

Inside my typeScript files, I sometimes need to refer to one of the other components so I end up with code that looks like:

```
import { something } from '../../partB/BB'
import { another } from './subA/AAA'
```

Is there a way to setup webpack so that I can always specify the import path to my components relative to the root (**src**) folder rather than having a bunch of relative paths defined that are specific to the file which is using the import statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by using webpack's resolve alias: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

in conjunction with tsconfig.json (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).  I needed to specify a baseUrl and paths to match what I have setup in my resolve alias.